# Set Spark version for Sagemaker on Glue Dev Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

To create my Glue scripts, I use development endpoints with Sagemaker notebooks that run the Pyspark (Sparkmagic) kernel.
The latest version of Glue (version 1.0) supports Spark 2.4. However, my Sagemaker notebook uses Spark version 2.2.1. 
The function I want to test only exists as of Spark 2.3. 
Is there a way to solve this mismatch between the dev endpoint and the Glue job? Can I somehow set the Spark version of the notebook?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a SageMaker notebook for the Glue dev endpoint, it launches a SageMaker notebook instance with a specific lifecycle configuration. This LC provides the configurations to create a connection between the SageMaker notebook and the development endpoint. Upon running cells from the PySpark kernel, the code is sent to the Livy server running in the development endpoint via REST APIs.

Thus, the PySpark version that you see and on which the SageMaker notebook runs depends on the development endpoint and is not configurable from the SageMaker point of view.

Since Glue is a managed service, root access is restricted for the development endpoint. Thus, you cannot update the spark version to a more later version. The feature of using Spark version 2.4 has been newly introduced in Glue and it seems that it has not yet been released for dev endpoint.